# Xlsxwriter: format three cell ranges in same worksheet

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I would like to format `A1:E14` as US Dollars, `F1:K14` as percentages and `A15:Z1000` as US Dollars. Is there a way to do this in XlsxWriter?

I know how to format full columns as Dollars/Percentages, but I don't know how to format parts of columns -- whatever I do last will overwrite Columns `F:K`.

Data is starting in pandas so happy to solve the problem there. The following does not seem to work:

```
sheet.set_column('A1:E14', None, money_format)
```

More Code:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter(write_path) as writer:
    book = writer.book
    money_fmt = book.add_format({'num_format': '$#,##0'})
    pct_fmt = book.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
    # call func that creates a worksheet  named total with no format
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Total', startrow=0)
    other_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Total', startrow=15)
    writer.sheets['Total'].set_column('A1:E14',20, money_fmt)
    writer.sheets['Total'].set_column('F1:K14',20, pct_fmt)
    writer.sheets['Total'].set_column('F15:Z1000', 20, money_fmt)
```

Comment: Can you add sample and your code to question?

Comment: Thank you. I think better is add it to question - nicer formatting.

Comment: Added to question, thanks

Comment: Do you need to format the cells without writing any data in? I usually specify the format when I write in the data.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see a way to achieve per cell formatting using just `xlsxwriter` with Pandas, but it would be possible to apply the formatting in a separate step using `openpyxl` as follows:

```
import openpyxl

def write_format(ws, cell_range, format):
    for row in ws[cell_range]:
        for cell in row:
            cell.number_format = format

sheet_name = "Total"

with pd.ExcelWriter(write_path) as writer:
    write_worksheet(df, writer, sheet_name=sheet_name)  

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(write_path)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)   

money_fmt = '$#,##0_-'
pct_fmt = '0.00%'

write_format(ws, 'A1:G1', money_fmt)
write_format(ws, 'A1:E14', money_fmt)
write_format(ws, 'F1:K14', pct_fmt)
write_format(ws, 'F15:Z1000', money_fmt)    

wb.save(write_path)
```

When attempted with `xlsxwriter`, it always overwrites the existing data from Pandas. But if Pandas is then made to re-write the data, it then overwrites any applied formatting. There does not appear to be any method to apply formatting to an existing cell without overwriting the contents. For example, the [write_blank()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#write_blank) function states:

> This method is used to add formatting to a cell which doesn’t contain
>   a string or number value.

Comment: if I call this after `df.to_excel` it overwrites data. If I call it before, df.to_excel raises  `Exception: Sheetname 'Total' with case ignored, is already in  use`.

Comment: edited my question to clarify where I am writing the data to the sheet

Comment: It would appear this is not possible. I have updated to include a version that achieves the same thing using openpyxl. You might need to investigate the available formatting options further.